# Does lightning on Venus affect the chemical composition of the clouds?

Tags: planetary-atmosphere, venus, astrochemistry

[It is established that lightning occurs on Venus due to the presence of sulfuric acid clouds](https://www.nasa.gov/vision/universe/solarsystem/venus-20071128.html). Does this constant electric discharges and possible electrolysis affects the composition of the clouds on Venus for instance, sulfuric acid dissociating into ions like hydrogen ions, sulfate/bisulfate ions or decomposing into sulfur oxides or changing to other sulfur oxoacids?

There was a [question on space.SE](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/38242/could-h%E2%82%82s%E2%82%82o%E2%82%88-peroxydisulfuric-acid-made-in-the-clouds-of-venus-be-used-for-m) that discussed if peroxydisulfuric acid (H<sub>2</sub>S<sub>2</sub>O<sub>8</sub>) created due to electrolysis of concentrated sulfuric acid (from the lightning) can be used as a propellant fuel. If the species is indeed formed in the atmosphere, how abundant is it? How much of this species is present in the atmosphere?

Does lightning on Venus change/affect the chemical composition of the clouds? Does it affect [the sulfur cycle of Venus](https://www.lpi.usra.edu/meetings/lpsc2009/pdf/2559.pdf) in any way (so that it could create more exotic sulfur species)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Observations by many spacecraft that have visited Venus over the last
> 40 years appear to confirm the presence of lightning storms in the
> Venus atmosphere. Recent observations by Venus Express indicate that
> lightning frequency and power is similar to that on Earth. **While
> storms are occurring, energy deposition by lightning into Venus
> atmospheric constituents will immediately dissociate molecules into
> atoms, ions and plasma from the high temperatures in the lightning
> column (>30,000 K) and the associated shock waves and heating, after
> which these atom and ion fragments of C,O,S,N,H-containing molecules
> will recombine during cooldown to form new sets of molecules.** Spark
> and discharge experiments suggest that lightning
> effects on the main atmospheric molecules CO2, N2, SO2, H2SO4 and H2O
> will yield carbon oxides and suboxides (CO<sub>m</sub>, C<sub>n</sub>O<sub>m</sub>), sulfur oxides
> (S<sub>n</sub>O, S<sub>n</sub>O<sub>m</sub>), oxygen (O2), elemental sulfur (S<sub>n</sub>), nitrogen oxides (NO,
> N2O, NO2), sulfuric acid clusters (H<sub>n</sub>S<sub>m</sub>O<sub>x</sub><sup>−</sup>.aH<sub>n</sub>S<sub>m</sub>O<sub>x</sub> e.g. HSO<sub>4</sub><sup>−</sup>.mH<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub>),
> polysulfur oxides, carbon soot and other exotic species. While the
> amounts generated in lightning storms would be much less than that
> derived from photochemistry, during storms these species can build up
> in a small area and so their local concentrations may increase
> significantly. [...]

**Source**: M.L. Delitsky, K.H. Baines, Storms on Venus: Lightning-induced chemistry and predicted products, Planetary and Space Science, Volumes 113–114, 2015,Pages 184-192, [10.1016/j.pss.2014.12.005](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0032063314003973)